# Crear td con el mismo id del th, Ocultar th con sus td

Tags: html, jquery, tablas, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla con sus `th` con *id* y después le agrego los datos con `td`

```html
<table id="tblCustomers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="Persona" style="width:120px">Tipo Persona</th>
            <th id="datos" style="width:120px">Datos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];
    var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

    var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
    cell.addClass("Mayus");
    cell.html($('#TipoPersona  :selected').text());
```

Tengo dos preguntas.

1. ¿Cómo agregar el `td` con el mismo *ID* del `th`?
2. ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar el `td` con sus correspondientes `th`?

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer pero no pueden existir dos elementos con el mismo id

Comment: En vez de usar un atributo [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/id) para agrupar elementos relacionados, podrías usar el atributo [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/className), o incluso podrías usar algún atributo tipo [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/data-*). Saludos

Comment: @DavidOchoa este link quizá te sea de utilidad, es una librería js que permite hacer algo parecido a lo que mencionas http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, tome tu consejo.

Answer (score 0):

Como tal no es necesario asignes `id`; con que hagas referencia al objeto; ademas que los `ìd` deben ser únicos por página.

A continuación podrás observar que sin asignar `id` se puede hacer el ocultar; también agrego botón para **mostrar todos**; espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
function ocultarme(elTR) {
  $(elTR).hide();
}


function mostrarTodos() {
  $("#tblCustomers tbody tr").show();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button onclick="mostrarTodos()" class="btn btn-success">Mostrar todos</button>
<br /><br />
<table id="tblCustomers" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="Persona" style="width:120px">Tipo Persona</th>
            <th id="datos" style="width:120px">Datos</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr onclick="ocultarme(this)">
            <td>1er columna fila 1</td>
            <td>2da colum FILA 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="ocultarme(this)">
            <td>1er columna fila 2</td>
            <td>2da columan fila 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```